# Binary search when a part of array was reversed

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, binary-search

Given an array(size N) (sorted but some part of it was reversed), And a series of elements (Q), we have to output Yes/No based on whether the element is present or not in the array.

The solution which I came up was as below:

1. Do a linear traversal and find out the indexes where the array was reversed.
2. For each query of element, Call Binary Search on 3 sub-arrays (the first sub-array, the reversed sub-array and the remaining sub-array)

The time complexity is `O(N + Q* log N).` I wonder if we can do it in `O(Q * Log N)` avoiding the first step?

Comment: *Q* is the number of elements you want to check if they are in the array?

Comment: In which circumstances did you have to handle this kind of bizarre ordered data? Or is this homework?

Comment: @MrSmith42 yes. Q is the number elements. It's an interview question

Comment: If `Q >= N`, then sorting the array will cost `[N * log N]` and total cost of all `Q` searches will be `[Q * log N]`. Individual search = `[log N]`

Comment: Can there be duplicates?

Comment: How do you get the N numbers as input if you not do at least O(N) traversal once?

Comment: @shole Assume that Array will be taken as a parameter, we don't read it from user input.

Comment: @kfx let's assume there are no duplicates as well.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in **log(n)**:

there can be mainly 3 cases: reversed sub-array sharing both halves (1  **5 4 3 2** 6 7) or completely lies on first half ( 1 **3 2** 4 5 6 7) or second half( 1 2 3 4 **6 5** 7).

1) Initially, just go through the normal binary search and keep searching till either

(i) you found the needed element or
   (ii) you encounter the reversed sub-array (i.e. when element at index (l+h)/2 is smaller than prev_element and greater than next_element).
If encountered reversed sub-array then proceed with **2).**

2) When reversed sub-array shares the both halves i.e. cuts through the middle index then this is the case of **pivoted array approach**. apply below mentioned *pivoted array approach* for **both** first and second half of the array and see if element is found.
 2*log(n) ~ log(n).
Make sure to handle corner cases as well.

***Overall time complexity: log(n)***

---

**Pivoted array approach:**

Remember that half of the array will still be sorted.
So, you can still find the element in `log(n)` by slightly modifying the binary search.

```
Input arr[] = {3, 4, 5, 1, 2}
Element to Search = 1
 1) Find middle point mid = (l + h)/2
 2) If key is present at middle point, return mid.
 3) Else If arr[l..mid] is sorted
    a) If key to be searched lies in range from arr[l]
       to arr[mid], recur for arr[l..mid].
    b) Else recur for arr[mid+1..r]
 4) Else (arr[mid+1..r] must be sorted)
    a) If key to be searched lies in range from arr[mid+1]
       to arr[r], recur for arr[mid+1..r].
    b) Else recur for arr[l..mid]
```

Very nice article on [www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-an-element-in-a-sorted-and-pivoted-array/](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-an-element-in-a-sorted-and-pivoted-array/)

Comment: what if the array is {1, 2, 4, 3 , 5}

Comment: How do you know *"If arr[l..mid] is sorted"* without reading all the elements in the intervall?

Comment: *'reversed'* is not the same as *'rotated'*. Also we do not know **l** and **h**. The question is about if we really need to search for them because this might need O(n) time.

Comment: @MrSmith42 we are finding l and h by binary search. see the updated answer

Comment: @JerryGoyal: I don't see how you can find l an h with binary search. You cannot know if each of them is left or right of the pivot element.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I see the problem with l and h though, i've come-up with another approach. let me know if you found some issue with it. see the updated answer

Comment: @JerryGoyal: Example: 124**3**567 and you look for **4**. You would binary search the right interval 567 (because **4** is greater than the pivot **3**) and you will never find the **4** or the reversed interval. So there is the possibility to neither find element nor find the reversed array.

Comment: @MrSmith42 gud morning:) it's possible. in 1st iteration of BS, the middle element is a[3] = 3. 3 is not equal to 4 then we check if it's part of sub-array(notice the 2nd condition in 1)). yes it is, becuz 4>3<5. so we first take the first half of array: 1 2 4 and perform BS on it. please let me know if u need further explanation.

Comment: I don't quite understand the algorithm. if you do binary search, you need to divide the array into two parts and decide which part to search. If input is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 10] then how do you divide and decide which part to search?

Comment: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 10] is not a sorted and reversed array. my algo can only apply to sorted array with some part of it reversed. that's what OP mentioned.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the op question, but it is reversed at 8, 6?
Or  what if input is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10], it can be obtained by first sorted [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] then reverse 8, 9

Comment: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10] is a valid sorted reverse array and my algo will work for it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. Do you mind telling me the first few steps that your algorithm will take? Like which elements to look at and how to divide the array and how to decide which part to search? Thanks.

Comment: let's take [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8, 10] and will look for 8. pick middle element and compare: arr[(0+9)/2] = 5. we'll look on right side of array becuz 5<8 and 5 is not part of reversed sub-array. arr[(5+9)/2] = 9. here 9 is part of reversed sub-arr so check on its left & right side. left side: arr[5], arr[6]. do BS. 8 not found. go for right side: arr[8],arr[9]. do BS. element found.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I still don't get it and have a few questions.
1. How does the algorithm know that it should look for 8?
2. Even if it knows it should find 8, how does it know that it should look at the right side? The array can be [1, 10, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12], and the reverse part is at the left. (Note that the fifth element is also 5)

Comment: how on god's green earth is [1, 10, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12]  a sorted reverse array? did you even understand the question? and the thing about finding 8 I'm not sure you know about Binary search or not.

Comment: Oh sorry, that is my mistake, how about [1, 10, 8, 6, 5, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]? reverse part is 10, 8, 6, 5. And how about my first question? How do you know that you are going to look for 8 at the start? Don't worry, I do know binary search. But in a binary search, we know what item to search for in the start. I don't think we have any information about what item to search for in this question

Comment: My idea is that in general the reverse part can be very shot (e.g. only 2 items). When n is large, almost everyplace of the array looks like a normal sorted array. Then when you do binary search, how do you know where the reverse part is hiding if you only look at the middle element. Or it would be great if you can provide the code and we can discuss on it.

Answer (score 0):

You know that the array consists of three portions, ascending, descending, ascending. So you can find the two critical points by sampling. It's somewhat tricky, once you find a point in the reversed section it's then easy enough (just two binary searches). Finding the reversed section is harder. If we sample and array[i+1] < array[i], we've found it. But if we miss it, we don't know if we're too high or too low, so we need a queue with intervals to test. We start with one interval, and sample the middle. That gives us two intervals, so we sample the middle of those, which gives us four intervals, and so on, until we've found an index into the reversed section.

Comment: If we are unlucky this leads us to look at every element O(n). So no improvement in worst case to linear looking through the array to find the reveres interval.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. First of all what we need is some kind of way to find a breaking point by that I mean the following :let's say we have an array {1,2,3,4,9,8,7,6} notice the number 9 at index 4 it is a breaking point because the sorting direction is changed now the important part is to find it in log(n).For that purpose, I created the following class.For this class to work he needs to get an array of the following type {sorted,reverseSorted}

```
public class BreakPointSearcher {
private int array[];
private BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Boolean> compare;
private Map<Boolean, Direction> directions;

public BreakPointSearcher(int[] array, BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Boolean> compare) {
    this.array = array;
    this.compare = compare;
}

public int findTheBreackingPoint(int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end || end >= array.length)
        return -1;

    loadDirectionMap(start, end);
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    if (isBreackingPoint(mid))
        return mid;

    Direction direction = getDirection(mid);
    //Using recursive call by that making the algorithm run in O(log(n))
    if (GoRight == direction) {
        return findTheBreackingPoint(mid + 1, end);
    } else if (GoLeft == direction) {
        return findTheBreackingPoint(start, mid - 1);
    }

    return -1;
}

/**
 * I assume that two sides of the array have opposite sorting
 * that is if at the start we have ascending at the end we have descending
 */
private void loadDirectionMap(int start, int end) {
    directions = new HashMap<>();
    directions.put(compare.apply(array[start], array[start + 1]), GoRight);
    directions.put(compare.apply(array[end - 1], array[end]), GoLeft);
}

private Direction getDirection(int mid) {
    return directions.get(compare.apply(array[mid], array[mid + 1]));
}

private boolean isBreackingPoint(int mid) {
    boolean inBetween = compare.apply(array[mid - 1], array[mid]) && compare.apply(array[mid + 1], array[mid]); // a > b < c
    boolean inBetweenTypeTwo = compare.apply(array[mid], array[mid - 1]) && compare.apply(array[mid], array[mid + 1]); // a < b > c
    return inBetween || inBetweenTypeTwo;
}

enum Direction {
    GoLeft,
    GoRight
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] arrayNums = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 20, 9, 8};
    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Boolean> compareAsc = (a, b) -> a > b;
    BreakPointSearcher sbs = new BreakPointSearcher(arrayNums, compareAsc);
    System.out.println(sbs.findTheBreackingPoint(0, arrayNums.length - 1)); //output is 7

    arrayNums = new int[]{252, 48, 22, 10, 12, 13, 16};
    sbs = new BreakPointSearcher(arrayNums, compareAsc);
    System.out.println(sbs.findTheBreackingPoint(0, arrayNums.length - 1)); //output 3

    arrayNums = new int[]{22, 56, 13};
    sbs = new BreakPointSearcher(arrayNums, compareAsc);
    System.out.println(sbs.findTheBreackingPoint(0, arrayNums.length - 1)); //output 1

    arrayNums = new int[]{22, 56, 78, 33};
    sbs = new BreakPointSearcher(arrayNums, compareAsc);
    System.out.println(sbs.findTheBreackingPoint(0, arrayNums.length - 1)); //output 2

    arrayNums = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
    sbs = new BreakPointSearcher(arrayNums, compareAsc);
    System.out.println(sbs.findTheBreackingPoint(0, arrayNums.length - 1)); //output -1

    arrayNums = new int[]{4, 3, 2, 1};
    sbs = new BreakPointSearcher(arrayNums, compareAsc);
    System.out.println(sbs.findTheBreackingPoint(0, arrayNums.length - 1)); //output -1

}
```

}

Now that we have such class we can start a binary search what I am going to do is to search for the key if it is found the function is finished if at some point the algorithm notices that the sort is reversed it will go to the left and to the right of that point and will search for bounds of the reversed array after that we have 3 arrays in each we perform binary search (in one of them it is reverse) and that's it.It is not a perfect solution and will probably in some special cases but as general idia I think it is correct

```
public class SpecialBinarySearch {

private static BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Boolean> ascComp = (a, b) -> a > b;
private static BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Boolean> dscComp = (a, b) -> a < b;

public static int search(int[] array, int key, int start, int end, BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Boolean> compare) {
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    if (array[mid] == key)
        return mid;
    if (start == end)
        return -1;

    boolean opositeSorted = compare.apply(array[mid], array[mid + 1]);
    if (opositeSorted) {
        BreakPointSearcher breakPointSearcher = new BreakPointSearcher(array, compare);
        int leftBound = breakPointSearcher.findTheBreackingPoint(0, mid);
        int rightBound = breakPointSearcher.findTheBreackingPoint(mid, array.length - 1);

        leftBound = leftBound == -1 ? 0 : leftBound; //
        rightBound = rightBound == -1 ? array.length - 1 : rightBound;

        int opt1 = search(array, key, leftBound, rightBound, getOpositeCompare(compare));
        int opt2 = search(array, key, start, leftBound, compare);
        int opt3 = search(array, key, rightBound, end, compare);

        return Math.max(Math.max(opt1, opt2), opt3);
    }

    if (compare.apply(key, array[mid])) {
        return search(array, key, mid + 1, end, compare);
    } else {
        return search(array, key, start, mid - 1, compare);
    }
}

private static BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Boolean> getOpositeCompare(BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Boolean> compare) {
    return compare == ascComp ? dscComp : ascComp;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 20, 25};
    System.out.println(search(array, 20, 0, array.length - 1, ascComp)); //output 3

    array = new int[]{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 3};
    System.out.println(search(array, 6, 0, array.length - 1, dscComp));//output 4

    array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16};
    System.out.println(search(array, 18, 0, array.length - 1, ascComp));//output 7

    array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20, 19, 18, 22, 25};
    System.out.println(search(array, 22, 0, array.length - 1, ascComp));//output 8

    array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16};
    System.out.println(search(array, 16, 0, array.length - 1, ascComp));//output 9

    array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16};
    System.out.println(search(array, 2, 0, array.length - 1, ascComp));//output 1

}
```

}